# Select Query 01722 issue with date Column

Tags: oracle, date-range, ora-01722

We have a issue where i am selecting few columns from view. this   Select Query throwing 01722 issue with date Column. please help in resolving this issue. also let me know why it says invalid number.

My Table Structure is given below.

```
GRE 1 VARCHAR2 (720 Byte) Y
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER 2 VARCHAR2 (30 Byte) Y
FULL_NAME 3 VARCHAR2 (240 Byte) Y
EMPLOYEE_CATEGORY 4 VARCHAR2 (80 Byte) Y
TERMINATION_DATE 5 DATE Y
LAST_UPDATE_DATE 6 DATE Y
RESIGNATION_NOTIFICATION_DATE 7 DATE Y
WORK_LOCATION 8 VARCHAR2 (30 Byte) Y
WORK_COUNTRY 9 VARCHAR2 (60 Byte) Y
PAYROLL_VENDOR_CODE 10 VARCHAR2 (3 Byte) Y
PTO_PAYOUT_HOURS 11 VARCHAR2 (60 Byte) Y
FLH_PAYOUT_HOURS 12 VARCHAR2 (60 Byte) Y
PAYROLL_COUNTRY 13 VARCHAR2 (80 Byte) Y
SUPERVISOR_NAME 14 VARCHAR2 (240 Byte) Y
SUPERVISOR_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER 15 VARCHAR2 (30 Byte) Y
HR_MANAGER 16 VARCHAR2 (240 Byte) Y
TERMINATION_REASON 17 VARCHAR2 (80 Byte) Y
NORMAL_WORK_HOURS 18 NUMBER (22,3) Y
FLSA 19 VARCHAR2 (10 Byte) Y
CURRENT_PERIOD_PTO_TAKEN 20 NUMBER Y
CURRENT_PERIOD_FH_TAKEN 21 NUMBER Y
JOB_TITLE 22 VARCHAR2 (700 Byte) Y
```

I tried the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM `ALL_EMP_TERM_PAYOUT_V` WHERE trim( TERMINATION_DATE )
<= TO_DATE('03-05-2015','MM-DD-YYYY') and trim( TERMINATION_DATE )>= 
TO_DATE('03-05-2015','MM-DD-YYYY')
```

If I choose only few columns, I am not getting this error. where as if give select * ........... I am getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about you change your statement to:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_EMP_TERM_PAYOUT_V 
   WHERE TERMINATION_DATE between TO_DATE('03-05-2015-00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY-HH24:MI:SS') 
                              and TO_DATE('03-05-2015-23:59:59','MM-DD-YYYY-HH24:MI:SS')
```

Oracle 'Trim' is a function that is supposed to be used with a strings, not dates. You might be experiencing some unwanted implicit casts.

Have a look on the [documentation for the trim function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php) for further details.

*Please add the table creation script(s) and the view creation scrip(s) if this does not answer your question*